# Location is not set

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I created a project wich contains a simple window with graphic contents using scene builder (FXML), I got this error:

here a capture of the code:

[image: code capture]

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:16)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Don't post code as images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the view loader to (line 14) :

```
final FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = 
new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/MaScene.fxml");
```

Comment: Yea It works. Thank you for your help ^^